# How can I redirect to shorten url from original url?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder `xampp/test/a/user/*` and I have done url shorten like `localhost/login.php` instead of `localhost/test/a/user/login.php` as below htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ test/a/user/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I want to restrict direct url access .Example if I access by `localhost/test/a/user/login.php` , I want to redirect to shorten url or some error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteBase` to redirect to shorter URL:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test/a/user/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```